# Seeing the document root instead of my rails app running, Ubuntu VPS with Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am running ubuntu on my VPS and have installed apache as well as phusion passenger to deploy my rails apps with. I went through the setup for phusion passenger and everything installed just fine. I edited the apache configuration files and have appended the information below. I have also made sure that the Virtualhost is not being overridden the default host and when I changed that and refreshed a browser I was brought to the public directory of my rails app instead of having the rails app being executed. Any help would be appreciated.

additions to /etc/apache/apache2.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
PassengerDefaultUser www-data


<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/bodylabel/globify/public
    <Directory /home/bodylabel/globify/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/host.conf

```
# The "order" line is only used by old versions of the C library.
order hosts,bind
multi on
```

Just ran sudo passenger-status and got back the following:

```
*** Cleaning stale folder /tmp/passenger.44591
*** Cleaning stale folder /tmp/passenger.44300
*** Cleaning stale folder /tmp/passenger.44372
*** Cleaning stale folder /tmp/passenger.44200
*** Cleaning stale folder /tmp/passenger.21157
*** Cleaning stale folder /tmp/passenger.43944
*** Cleaning stale folder /tmp/passenger.21589
*** Cleaning stale folder /tmp/passenger.44878
ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.
```

Comment: Just to know, why are you using Apache?

Comment: @DmitryPolushkin no special reason, any other suggestions?

Comment: apache is too heavy. Use nginx :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have two `VirtualHost` with the ip/port name `*:80`.  Apache will do one of two things here.  **If** you have a matching `NameVirtualHost` directive in your config then it will look for `ServerName` (and `ServerAlias`) directives within those two virtual host sections, **and if** the incoming request matches those server names/aliases then it will serve that virtual host.

Otherwise, it will serve the first `VirtualHost` block that is defined first in your configuration files.  So, which one is being served will depend on the order that `sites-enabled/000-default` is included relative to the location of the `VirtualHost` section in `apache2.conf`

Answer (score 0):

the obligatory dumb question, but, did you restart apache?

Also, although this probably isn't the source of your problem, you may want to use the debian-esque method of deploying sites here and drop that virtualhost config into `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and run `a2ensite` to activate it.

There's probably a similar construct in place for modules-available and modules-enabled, where you might put that passenger code, rather than in apache2.conf.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I did restart apache after the a2ensite mod.